# How to read selector

Tags: assembly, microprocessors

How to read that selector any one have idea ?

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Comment: What seems to be the problem? A major issue with the exercise is that the value of the G/LDTR is given but no memory for that pointer is shown. In fact, the professor meant something like G/LDTR.Base.

Comment: @MargaretBloom : I also find it interesting that what they should reference as a LDTR.base is a 32-bit value yet they say this is for an 80286 where the base is a 24-bit value. The base should have a linear address between 0 and 2^24-1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first page the selector is SS = 001Ah. The h denotes that the number  is represented in  hexadecimal notation. The hexadecimal number is then converted into binary notation, 0000-0000-0001-1010.

On the second page the selector is DS = 001Fh. Converted to binary notation the value is 0000-0000-0001-1000.

Check the link below for resource that may help.
Selectors and Descriptors:
https://www.byclb.com/TR/Tutorials/microprocessors/ch2_1.htm

Conveting Hex to Binary: http://math.tutorvista.com/number-system/convert-hexadecimal-to-binary.html

80285 Data Sheet: 
http://www.nj7p.info/Manuals/PDFs/Intel/210760-002.pdf

Comment: `1F = 0001_1111` ... what am I missing?

Comment: @Ped They dropped the low three bits to get the index into the descriptor table. But it is inappropriate to call that the selector.

Comment: @prl Why is it incorrect to call  it the selector? Due to the my usage of 0000-0000-0001-1000 or something else? I'm not disputing what you said just trying to get a better understanding and not mislead others since I am not familiar with these kinds of chips.

Comment: The low 3 bits are part of the selector. When you mask them off, you have a different value, so it's not the selector value any more. (It is the descriptor table index.)